# On integer sequences of the form $\sum_{n=1}^N (a(n))^2H_n^2,$ where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number: refute my conjecture and add yourself example

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, harmonic-numbers

After I've read a problem posed by Édouard Lucas from the first paragraph of the biography from this [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas) I am trying to get different variations of this problem using number theoretic functions. After I did some experiments (I've calculated some terms using Wolfram Alpha online calculator) I posed a surprising conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Here $H_n$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number. For each integer $n\geq 1$, the integer $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k!)^2(H_k)^2\tag{1}$$
is a square-free integer (has no repeated primes in its factorization, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer); we get $1$ as $n=1$).

> **Question 1.** Can you refute numerically my conjecture? Can you provide us some reasoning about if our sequence $(1)$ has infinitely many terms being square-free integers? **Many thanks.**

As you see I tried to get a variation of the problem posed by Lucas, since my proposal in the RHS of my problem is the sequence of square-free integers instead of the square numbers, and the terms of my finite series are the squares of the integers $k!\cdot H_k$. I tried more examples using number theoretic functions.

With the purpose of making this post more interesting I ask to this commmunity about other possible variations, and in order to ask a concise question, I am going to limit the nature of the sequences that are terms in our summation, now the square of sequences of the form $$a(k)\cdot H_k,$$
where $a(k)$ is a sequence of rational numbers. The RHS of your statement/conjecture can be any sequence (I prefer some interesting sequence of figurate numbers, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FigurateNumber.html)).

> **Question 2.** Provide us yourself example of a conjecture or statement from a sequence $a(k)$ or rational numbers, such that for each $n>N$ (for a suitable positive integer in your proposal) $N$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n (a(k)\cdot H_k)^2=\text{ a sequence of integers* }.\tag{2}$$
>   *I prefer figurate numbers, or famous sequences of integers like prime numbers... **Many thanks.**

Comment: Everyone I hope that my conjecture is having many right terms. On the other hand feel free to explore similar variations than mine, $(2)$ or different. Good week.

Comment: Now I remember that $k!H_k$ is a sequence from the literature, thus maybe my conjecture was in the literature. Refers it answering as a reference request for Question 1, if it is the case.

Comment: The fact that your sum gives integers is no surprise since $H_k$ by definition can't have any factors in its denominator which are not already contained in $k!$. But a nice sequence in any case, outputs some huge prime numbers

Comment: Here's the sequence defined by a slightly more simple sum http://oeis.org/A097422 $$\sum_{k=1}^n n! H_n$$ The sequence defined by (1) is not in OEIS, you can apply it there if you think it's interesting

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @YuriyS I am going to wait what saying the users. On the other hand I accept if some user want to apply this sequence refering this MSE.